# struct size not as expected when using bit fields

Tags: c++, struct, padding, bit-fields

With the below code:

```
struct S {
unsigned char b1 : 3;
int i;
};
```

I can deduce that char b1 is of 1 byte and using 3 bits of that and int is 4 bytes but when I try to print out the size of S, I get it 8 bytes instead of 5 bytes(1 for char+4 for int) as I expected and this is something I am not understanding by obvious.
Can something explain why size of S is 8 bytes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968468/padding-in-structures-in-c?lq=1

Comment: run this code on vc++ and gcc compiler and result is same.

Comment: And the reason is the same too. Have you read the link? Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761994/size-of-a-structure-containing-bit-fields?rq=1)? Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)?