# why size of structure does not change when use 24 bit integer

Tags: c++

I am trying to port embed code in windows platform.
I have come across below problem I am posting a sample code here.
here even after I use int24 size remains 12 bytes in windows why ?

```
struct INT24
{
    INT32 data : 24;
};

struct myStruct
{
    INT32 a;
    INT32 b;
    INT24 c;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned char myArr[11] = { 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF };
    myStruct *p = (myStruct*)myArr;
    cout << sizeof(*p);
}
```

Comment: Think about `myStruct[N]` and alignment.

Comment: `INT32 data : 24;` still occupies 4 bytes.

Comment: but I am forcing it to use 3 bytes.

Comment: Compiler and/or OS allocate 4 bites at a time...

Comment: any way or workaround ? badly stuck because of this.

Comment: You can try creating the bitfields directly in `myStruct`, but there are no guarantees that they won't be padded therein either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [size of a structure containing bit fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761994/size-of-a-structure-containing-bit-fields)

Comment: @vivek set alignment to 1 byte (compiler specific) and use a 3 bytes array instead of a bitfield (which will result in no less than type you specified - INT32). See specs §9.6

Comment: I checked with my embedded friends they use something __attribute__ ((__packed__)) at end of structure. anything in VC ?

Comment: [Visual C++ equivalent of GCC's `__attribute__ ((__packed__))`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1537964/995714)

Comment: [Working with Packing Structures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253935%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons, each of which would be enough by themselves.

- Presumably the size of `INT32` is 4 bytes. The size of `INT24` is also 4 bytes, because it contains a `INT32` bit field. Since, `myStruct` contains 3 members of size 4, its size must therefore be at least 12.
- Presumably the alignment requirement of `INT32` is 4. So, even if the size of `INT24` were 3, the size of `myStruct` would still have to be 12, because it must have at least the alignment requirement of `INT32` and therefore the size of `myStruct` must be padded to the nearest multiple of 4.

> any way or workaround ?

This is implementation specific, but the following hack may work for some compilers/cpu combinations. See the manual of your compiler for the syntax for similar feature, and the manual for your target cpu whether it supports unaligned memory access. Also do realize that unaligned memory access does have a performance penalty.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct INT24
{
 INT32 data : 24;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct myStruct
{
INT32 a;
INT32 b;
INT24 c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Packing a bit field might not work the same in all compilers. Be sure to check how yours behaves.

I think that a standard compliant way would be to store char arrays of sizes 3 and 4, and whenever you need to read or write one of the integer, you'd have to `std::memcpy` the value. That would be a bit burdensome to implement and possibly also slower than the #pragma pack hack.

Comment: thanks for reply, but sadly it is not working with VS 2005 which I am using.

Comment: @vivek oh well, then use char arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly for you, the compiler in optimising the code for a particular architecture reserves the right to *pad* out the structure by inserting spaces between members *and* even at the end of the structure.

Using a bit field does *not* reduce the size of the `struct`; you still get the whole of the "fielded" type in the `struct`.

The standard guarantees that the address of the first member of a `struct` is the same as the address of the `struct`, *unless* it's a polymorphic type.

But all is not lost: you can rely on the fact that an *array* of `char` *will* always be contiguous and contain no packing.

If CHAR_BIT is defined as 8 on your system (it *probably* is), you can model an array of 24 bit types on an array of `char`. If it's not 8 then even this approach will not work: I'd then suggest resorting to inline assembly.

Comment: I don't think operating system cares about structure padding.

Comment: _the compiler and operating system reserve the right to pad out the structure by inserting spaces between members and even at the end of the structure_ still, some compilers have the mechanism (using pragma/attribute) for packed structures. However, that applies to case of `char;int;` case. For bit-fields, it will ALWAYS allocate entire sized (INT32 in this case) variables.

Comment: @PcAF: Indeed and have reworded a little.