# Is there a constant for max value for integer type?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm searching for a constant like MAXINT in c, for VBA code. I found references only in other languages, and cannot find one for VBA.

If there is no such constant what is the maximum number an int in VBA can hold?
I tried 2147483647 but got an overflow error.

Comment: An Integer in VBA has maximum value of 32767 and minimum of -32768

Comment: And for a `Long`, it's `2^31 - 1 = 2147483647`. AFAIK, there are no constants for that.

Comment: It should be noted that since we aren't using 16-bit environments anymore, it almost never makes sense to use Integer over Long.

Comment: @Andre If I understand you correctly, an Integer in VBA in my Win10 will always consume 4 bite?

Comment: @marlan: No. Integer = 2 bytes. But unless you create gigantic arrays, memory isn't really an issue anymore. Overflow is.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831804/why-size-of-structure-does-not-change-when-use-24-bit-integer#comment63125306_37831804) is a discussion (from today) on the topic in Visual C++, padding memory etc. VBA would not pad an Integer to 32bit?

Comment: @marlan: Heh, good question. I always took the 2 bytes for granted. I suggest you try it out, allocating large arrays and watching the memory usage with Process Explorer.

Comment: Ok @Andre here are my results: Before running code, MS Access Process consumed 12.8~9 MB. When running Dim intArr(100000) As Integer Process consumed 13.1 MB. When running Dim lngArr(100000) As Long Process consumed 13.3 MB. The above was tested some 3 times. **Conclusion: VBA doesn't pad integers in static integer arrays.** 
As for combinations of ints and lngs, these are actually arrays of Variatns or Objects (=refferences), and it is tough to conclude…

Answer (score 27, accepted):

VBA does not provide a `MAXINT` constant.  But you can derive that value easily:

```vb
MAXINT = (2 ^ 15) -1
Debug.Print MAXINT
 32767
```

Or you could define it as a `Public` constant with this in the Declarations section of a standard module:

```vb
Public Const MAXINT As Integer = (2 ^ 15) - 1
```

Then `MAXINT` would be available for the rest of your VBA code in that application.

And for `Long Integer`, the maximum value is ...

```vb
MAXLONG = (2 ^ 31) -1
Debug.Print MAXLONG
 2147483647
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we are here,,, 
lets complete the case and add a safety feature:

```
Dim MinInt As Integer
Dim MinLong As Long

MinInt = -2 ^ 15
MinLong = -2 ^ 31

Debug.Print MinInt, MinLong
     '     -32768  -2147483648
```

Comment: For us newbies, it would add interest to hear precisely why this achieves safety.