# Anything in code that could be causing a Overflow error in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Got a small Access file that people use.  They basically just enter a log of events.  They should be able to double click on a log event though and edit it if they misspelled something or anything else.  Well when double clicking in this "Memo" field, users are getting this error:

> Error 6 (Overflow) in procedure Memo_DblClick, line 0

When checking the event procedure on double click in this field this is the code for it:

```
Private Sub Memo_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    On Error GoTo Memo_DblClick_Error
Dim DID As Integer
DID = Me.detail_ID

DoCmd.OpenForm "FrmLogbookDetail", _
WhereCondition:="Detail_ID=" & DID
Forms![frmLogbookDetail].cmdDelete.Enabled = False
Forms![frmLogbookDetail].AllowAdditions = False
Forms![frmLogbookDetail].Caption = "Edit Log Entry"

    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Memo_DblClick_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Memo_DblClick, line " & Erl & "."

End Sub
```

This file is in 2 other locations on the network for different departments to use.  Those departments can edit the memo field with no errors or issues.  I checked those files code for this field and looks identical.  Not seeing what is causing the error to come up for this particular file.  Based on the error it seems like it's expecting one value but seeing another?

Comment: What happens if you change the declaration for DID to this? `Dim DID As Long`

Comment: ok that ended up working!  Weird that it works fine in the other 2 identical files with that DID as Integer statement, wonder what happened to this one to suddenly make it not work like that

Comment: It would fail any time `Me.detail_ID` holds a value greater than 32767.

Comment: BTW your custom error message will always show zero for the line number because `erl` only returns a non-zero number when you actually number the code lines.  Check out [Pinpointing the Exact Line Where A Crash Occurs](https://www.fmsinc.com/free/newtips/VBA/ErrorHandling/LineNumber.html)

Comment: ah ok thank you!  I am new to Access and SQl stuff, and the previous guy in my position was big on that.  I have been reverse engineering a lot of his stuff which has helped but yeah this one has stumped me, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When `DID` is declared as an integer, [the maximum value it can hold is 32767](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37837253/77335). Any  attempt to load a larger integer into that variable will trigger the overflow error.

Change the variable type from Integer to Long Integer so that it can accept values up to 2147483647:

```vb
'Dim DID As Integer
Dim DID As Long
```